# count nulls values in a entry (columns)

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

| ID | SPNR | SP1 | SP2 | SP2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2 | x | x |  |
| 02 | 2 | x |  |  |
| 03 | 3 | x | x |  |
| 04 | 2 | x |  |  |
| 05 | 3 | x | x | x |

SPNR is the amount of SP needed.

The first record is ok. In the second you need 2 but there is only one. In the third, 3 are needed and there are only two.

I need a query that lists the records that do not meet the condition (ID = 2 ,3, 4)

I am relatively new to MYSQL and cannot find the "count if" option for the same record. Can someone shed some light on me.

Comment: Please share expected output in table format for better idea

Comment: edited!
The result should be ID = 2,3,4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a boolean sum expression here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE (SP1 IS NULL) + (SP2 IS NULL) + (SP3 IS NULL) != SPNR;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim but it doesn't work. 
Error with +
MySQL said: Documentation

# 1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax near '+ NP3 IS NULL) <! NPNR LIMIT 0, 25' on line 3

Comment: The parentheses were off, it should work now.

Comment: Now its works perfect. Thanks so much